# Java 8 Streams IO - Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, java-8, java-stream

I've written a simple class whose reading and writing files by using a single stream.

Now I want to test it by using JUnit test or something like that but I have no clue where to start with this because as u can see this is only one stream and text is immediately printing to a new file.

```
public class OneStreamIOFile {

  public void fileReaderWriter(String fileReadPath, String filePrintName) {
    try (Stream<String> streamReader = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileReadPath));
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(filePrintName)) {

      streamReader
          .filter(line -> line.matches("[\\d\\s]+"))
          .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.trim().split("[\\s]+"))
              .reduce((a, b) -> a + "+" + b).get() + "="
              + Arrays.stream(line.trim().split("[\\s]+"))
              .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum())
          .forEachOrdered(printWriter::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Main class

```
  public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String filePath = "src/test/java/resources/1000.txt";
            String filePrintName = "resultStream.txt";

            new OneStreamIOFile().fileReaderWriter(filePath, filePrintName);
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: consider the clean code principle of **Single Responsibility Principle** - once you applied this you'll easily know how to test - your aler bells should already be ringing when you name your method **readwrite** ...

Comment: Using `PrintWriter` for such a task is evil. The minimum you should do, is to invoke [`checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--) afterwards to find out *if* an error occurred. Since you won’t find out *which* error occurred, you should stay away from `PrintWriter` in production code (unless truly writing to the console). As a side note, `Arrays.stream(line.trim().split("[\\s]+")) .reduce((a, b) -> a + "+" + b).get()` is quiet convoluted compared to `line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "+")`…

Comment: and by the way, `.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)` is boxing every value into an `Integer`, just to unbox it afterwards. You should prefer `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)`…

Comment: If you need to validate the text written to the file you have to read the file and do an assert equal.
I add sample to verify file write successfully.

Answer (score 2):

A unit test has to focus on the behavior, not on implementation details.
The way you are using to read from a stream and write to another stream doesn't matter.

Here you have to focus on what you have as **input** and as **ouput** of the method under test.

In input, you have `String fileReadPath` representing the file where you read from and and in output you have `String filePrintName`, the file created by the method under test.

So to unit test `OneStreamIOFile.fileReaderWriter()`, create an input test file and create an expected output test file containing what you expect as the input test file is passed to the method.
Of course store them in your test folders.

In your test, pass their `String` representation to the method under test.
Then, assert that the file created by the method has the same content as the expected output file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file has written by using below code snippet.

public class Sample {

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testFileReaderWriter() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    File file=temporaryFolder.newFile("sample.txt");
    Date createdTime=new Date();
    OneStreamIOFile options=new OneStreamIOFile();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    options.fileReaderWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(),"hellow");
    Date modifiedTime=new Date();
    Assert.assertTrue(createdTime.getTime()<modifiedTime.getTime());


}
```

}

You have to give some time after creating the file and if you need to check content you can read files content and assert it.

TemporyFolder is a rule using to handle file operations in Junit.